# Apex equivalent for lightning-relative-date-time component

Tags: apex

I'd like to get a friendly relative-to-now date string within Apex code.

The LWC [`lightning-relative-date-time`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-relative-date-time/example) and Aura [`lightning:relativeDateTime`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:relativeDateTime/example) components do this on the client side:

> Day SFDC was born - **February 1999: 21 years ago**
>
> Today 9:00 AM: **8 hours ago**
>
> Right now: **a few seconds ago**
>
> Future - **January 2050: in 30 years**

Does anyone know of a simple method / helper class that does this within Apex?

Comment: I suspect you'll have to write it all yourself!

Comment: @PhilW I also have that suspicion but hoping someone either has something we haven't thought of yet, or already wrote a nice helper class for this :-P